# SwiftUI - object are shown outside my HStack

Tags: swiftui

I wonder why are my Circles shown way below the point where my HStack ends?

[image]

1) I think they should have appeared within the top 50px but for some reason they are shown below that blue rectangle (representing my HStack) in the preview area.

2) I also don't understand why "test" is on my circles but not below them..

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            ForEach(weekData.weekDays, id: \.id) { day in
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.yellow)
                        .frame(width:45, height:45)
                        .opacity((self.journey.days[day.day] == nil) ? 0 : 1)
                    Circle()
                        .fill(day.today ? Color.blue : (day.active ? Color.black : Color.gray))
                        .frame(width:40, height:40)
                    Text("\(day.dof)")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 50)
        }
        .frame(height: 50)
        .offset(y:50)
        Text("test")
            .font(.headline)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        Spacer()
    }
    .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth, height: UIScreen.screenHeight)
}
```

Please advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to .offset

```
    }
    .frame(height: 50)
    .offset(y:50)       // << this !!
```

offset changes presentation, but not real layout frame of SwiftUI view.